# How to turn off case sensitive completion in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way to turn off case sensitive Completion for WebStorm? By default it uses case sensitive completion.

I searched net for this but could not find a  setting for it. All links lead to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion**, disable **Match case** - does it help?